# Change Sonar issues severity for all issues that have the same rule

Tags: sonarqube

In SonarQube, if I select:

- Severity - e.g.: Major
- Rule - e.g.: Don't use something

I am able to see a list of all problems.

If I click on a description, a popup is shown and there I can click More actions > **Change severity** and set another severity (e.g.: "Minor")

Is it possible to do this for **all** issues that have the same severity & rule? I have more than 1000 similar things.

I know that this change can be done from the profile, but the profile is "read-only".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- When you see a list having a specified (Severity, Rule), click on "**Bulk change**" (above that list, on the right side)

  - Disadvantage: the limit for a "bulk" is 500 issues. If you have 5000, you'll do this 10 times.
- Search for these issues on the "Issues" page and use the "**Bulk Change**" feature to update all those issues at once.

  - Disadvantage: not enough search criteria (can't select a specified Rule)

The changes will be preserved after a new deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case must be achieved by updating the quality profile. Just ask your SonarQube admin to grant you with proper permission (Administer Quality Profiles). See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-GlobalPermissions

Comment: The profile cannot be changed for the moment. This is why I was looking for a workaround. But don't delete your post, because it can be very useful for the other community members.